# custom upload form sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007

Can I create custom upload form in SharePoint for a picture library so that I can add code behind methods to it and do some filtering? I already tried event receivers but no gain only pain for multiple items, as if their dimensions were too long. Any type of tutorial will be fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a custom upload interface. I recommend either via a ASP.Net application page or a web part. You will be able to control the entire upload experience using your own interface like these. HTH

Comment: but how can i do sir, any tutorial please

Comment: This is a big task, I don't have a quick tutorial. Searching online for things like 'SharePoint custom application page' should get you there. You'll need VS2008/2010 (forget if 2010 works for SP2007) and I recommend the add on WSPBuilder for creating the necessary solution files.